# java - improve memory usage in this loop

Tags: java, loops, memory, heap-memory

I have a loop where I'm creating an object every time in the loop. With loop iteration increasing it will take a huge memory (although garbage collector collects it after sometime).

Here's the code

```
validatedExpOrders.values().forEach(validatedExpOrder -> {
            ExceptionOrderEO exceptionEO = new ExceptionOrderEO(); // object created            

            // set attributes
            exceptionEO.setOrder_id(validatedExpOrder.getOrderId());
            exceptionEO.setOrder_orig_trckg_nbr(validatedExpOrder.getOrigTrackingNbr());

            // set timestamps 
            exceptionEO.setCreate_ts(currentTimestamp);
            exceptionEO.setLast_change_ts(currentTimestamp);

            exceptionEOs.add(exceptionEO);
        });
```

And this function is returning array of objects which are getting created inside this loop.

Is there a way I can do it without creating an object in every iteration?

Comment: "this function is returning array of objects which are getting created inside this loop." - so you want to return an array of objects without creating them? How is that supposed to work? Besides the fact that you might want to consider using a collector, you seem to want to collect all those `ExceptionOrderEO` objects in `exceptionEOs` so if you need all that data then how should that be reduced?

Comment: Adding to @Thomas point, I think you are abusing `lambda` expressions here.

Comment: Btw, "it will take a huge memory" - how many objects are you talking about? What is "huge"? And if you really have _a lot_ of those objects, do you really need them in memory simultaneously?

Comment: @Thomas I was just looking for the suggestion or any other workaround. Apologies for my poor coding style. And I'm talking about some 80,000 objects which are making the application take about 1.5G when deployed on tomcat.

Comment: @Thomas. I'm looking for any other alternative to this? Any design suggestion is also appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted won't use much memory, at least if we assume `ExceptionOrderEO` doesn't contain much more than those 4 attributes, which are references to already existing objects anyways. Thus 80k of those objects should just need a few megabytes. Try with a normal for loop and see if memory consumption changes (I'd doubt it) or create a memory dump and analyze it.

Comment: i would suggest use batching and store ExceptionOrderEO in database and clear out the list after every 100 or 1000 (your call). Since, I do not know what you are doing with these ExceptionOrderEO, cant comment more on the same.

Comment: From a conceptual point of view you should think about whether you _really_ need all those 80k objects in memory at the same time. We can't tell you since we don't know your requirements, architecture etc.

Comment: @Thomas `ExceptionOrderEO` has many more attributes. I have just added few here to keep it clean. I will try using a for loop and see

Comment: @akshayapandey Batching and clearing the list makes sense. I will try it out.

Comment: Well, as others already mentioned – do you need to have those objects in memory? You could, for instance, as well process the `exceptionEO`'s immediately. This, of course, entirely depends on what exactly you are planning to do with the objects.